# "Character is not valid" VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

So what this does is copy a report from the resources onto the computer and run it. The code is:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim dir As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp
    Dim filename As String = dir + +"Report.exe"
    IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filename, My.Resources.Report)
    Process.Start(filename)
End Sub
```

It gives me an error for Process.Start saying

> "Character is not valid"

I made another form and wrote the Process.Start part and gave me no errors. I tried removing all the previous code and replacing "filename" in Process.Start with an actual directory but nothing helps. I really need to some help on this, thanks.

Comment: You seem to be missing something here? `dir + +"Report.exe"`

Comment: I mean, that part doesn't give me any errors. Its not any string. Its just the main Process.Start() code.

Comment: thanks for pointing out that extra "+" but sadly it didn't fix the error :(

Comment: Put option strict on and use & to concatenate strings. Also, have you tried manually running your report exe file after it was generated? Maybe the content is wrong.

Comment: My report works fine, I put on option strict and used "&" but I get the same error.

Comment: What's the value of filename?

Comment: I really don't know what happened but the error just went away after restarting visual basic. Strange. but it worked! Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Debug your code and inspect the value of `filename`.  I doubt that it is a valid filepath with the code shown.

Comment: I'll check that

Comment: It works. It runs the application fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What is likely occurring is that the temp folder is returning an invalid character. Instead, try using the [IO.Path.GetTempPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath(v=vs.110).aspx) method and also build the path by using the [IO.Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Here is an example of building the String:

```
Dim dir As String = IO.Path.GetTempPath
Dim filename As String = IO.Path.Combine(dir, "report.exe")
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! Restarting Visual Studio got rid of the error somehow, But I will use that instead.

Comment: @Enlightened - Yeah, I'd suggest doing that. Especially since IO.Path.Combine is meant to specifically build file path locations. But I'm glad you got it working, it's not very often the old "turn it off and back on" trick works ;)